# How to use transparent texture in the GLSL shading mode in BGE?

Tags: game-engine, transparency

I am using Blender 2.74.  Is it possible to use transparent texture in the GLSL shading mode in BGE?

I can get it working in the multitexture mode thought. But no matter how I try, I can't get it working in the GLSL shading mode.  Can anyone please explain how to get it working if it is at all possible.

Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First in Material tab enable **Z Transparency** and set Alpha to zero.

[image]

Then in the Material Texture you need to enable **Alpha** in Influence section.

[image]

Comment: Hi Denis: the transparency works in multitexture mode only, not in GLSL mode.

Comment: @ShungChing I use mostly GLSL mode, and thats the settings that work for me with the transparency.

Comment: @ShungChing I don't know why you say that. I've found that they only work in GLSL.

Comment: @Denis: I've experimented different settings with the original file so much that I didn't get the transparency working even if I followed your instruction. I decided to delete the object and start all over again and it is working now! Thanks for the explanation and the excellent snapshots.

Comment: @VinceScalia: I should have tested the instruction with a new Blender session. Thanks for your input.