# Transparent PNGs don't cast shadows (in BI)

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, transparency, shadows

Blender 2.77 - Blender Internal

Hello, I'm trying to make a simple animation about files entering an envelope. I have some troubles with "Import Images as Planes", they don't cast transparent shadows, despite I checked "Raytrace" (or Z-transparency) on them, and "Receive transparent shadows" on the envelope's material.

Envelope material settings, PNG settings, and the result:

[image: all-settings]

Here's the full project:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_9DH8lxMw2bSE9hbWNPXy1DWm8

The example is frame # 397

After days and days, I still can't understand where I go wrong. Please help...

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33214/texture-painting-transparent/33223

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30394/how-to-use-transparent-texture-in-the-glsl-shading-mode-in-bge/30395

Comment: I followed everything suggested in those two links but it doesn't work (that's why I asked the question and I attached the whole project).
Only thing I can't do is re-importing the PNGs, I'd have to redo all the animation job :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the "jpg" object and uncheck the "cast" option in the shadow tab.

[image]

If you want your object to cast a ray traced shadow you must add a ray tracing light (i.e. a sun lamp) and enable her ray trace option.
In your animation you will also have to move the object toward the camera to separate the plane of the object from the plane of the cast shadow.

[image]

Comment: That was the solution! The type of light! Thank you. Solved.

Comment: I don't see what to disable *Cast* option for because this will disable possibility of material to cast shadow at all. Also in BI when using *Raytraced* shading any tipe of lamp will be possible to cast shadows.